# How to keep a python server alive for running scheduled tasks on threads?

Tags: python-3.x, google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform, job-scheduling

I've coded a small backend app in Python (running on Google App Engine) to serve as a custom, remote scheduler for a couple of Google Cloud Functions I am using across different apps. Typically a Function would ask the backend to schedule a callback with a given payload. All is fine except from the fact that, on the backend app, the threads responsible for calling back my Cloud Functions often die after a few hours: https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ca0qW.jpg

It goes without saying that I am not `joining` the threads.

I've read around on Python SIGINT signals emitted by UNIX servers with Python, but I need to exclude more simple options first. Relevant portion of code below:

```py
import time 
from datetime import datetime, timedelta
import sched
from threading import Thread

scheduler = sched.scheduler(time.time, time.sleep)
scheduler.enterabs(schedTime, 1, callback, kwargs=payload)
t.thread = Thread(target=scheduler.run) #dispatching scheduler main function to thread
t.start()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would say that the instance is getting killed due to any of several reasons, those are listed [here](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python3/how-instances-are-managed#shutdown), so it’s highly probable after some hours one of those statements are fulfilled, I would guess these two:

- Your application runs out of Instance Hours quota.
- The instance exceeds the maximum memory for its configured instance_class.

You should also consider that App Engine will attempt to keep your instance running indefinitely, but at some point the instances are going to be killed and started again.

You can control the scaling of your App Engine application by using the [scaling elements](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python3/config/appref#scaling_elements) into your App Engine app.yaml file. For example you can set max_instances and min_instances to 1 so you ensure there’s always an instance running. Or use the manual scaling to set a static amount of instances.

Comment: Thank you very much for you detailed answer. I need to assess whether you are correct, however, in your hypothesis that it's nothing about my code that is responsible for this undesirable behaviour. Will work on your suggestions and let you know :)

Comment: Okay, my problem is solved. Since I've made substantive changes in my code I cannot put exactly my finger on what fixed it, but I think your input helped a very good deal, in particular registering a permanent couple of instances (what I did was to use queues and generators to bring some discipline to my threads). So thank you very much!